# Trying to upgrade from EE 2.5.5 to 2.9.90 - the infamous white screen problem

Tags: ee2-upgrades

So Im trying to upgrade an EE site and when I follow the instructions... 
All I get is a black white page.  No error messages, nothing.

Interesting when I enable debug=1 in index.php, I do see this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/run/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Autoloader.php on line 46

Any ideas or hints really appreciated.

I dont have any special modules or plugins.

Paul

Answer (score 3):

The error points you to line 46 of the Autoloader.php file. That line of code is:

```
if ( ! isset(static::$instance))
```

This line of code will only run in PHP 5.3.0 or newer.

---

[**ExpressionEngine 2.9 requires PHP 5.3.10 or newer**](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html) and you're getting the error because your PHP version is older than this.

Comment: You saved me from having a complete breakdown, for this I am grateful!

Comment: Happy to help!!